# Edit product selling location using mysql

Tags: mysql, e-commerce

I'm building a e-Commerce platform (PHP + MySQL) and I want to add a attribute (feature) to products, the ability to specify (enable/disable) the selling status for specific city.

Here are simplified tables:

**cities**

```
id  name  
==========
1  Roma
2  Berlin 
3  Paris
4  London
```

**products**

```
id  name   cities
==================
1  TV      1,2,4
2  Phone   1,3,4
3  Book    1,2,3,4
4  Guitar  3
```

In this simple example is easy to query (using FIND_IN_SET or LIKE) to check the availability of product for specific city.
This is OK for 4 city in this example or even 100 cities but will be practical for a large number of cities and for very large number of products?

For better "performance" or better **database design** should I add another table to table to JOIN in query (`productid`, `cityid`, `status`) ?

**availability**

```
id  productid  cityid  status
=============================
1  1           1       1
2  1           2       1
3  1           4       1
4  2           1       1
5  2           3       1
6  2           4       1
7  3           1       1
8  3           2       1
9  3           3       1
10 3           4       1
11 4           3       1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For better "performance" or better database design should I add
>   another table

YES definitely you should create another table to hold that information likewise you posted rather storing in `,` separated list which is against `Normalization` concept. Also, there is no way you can gain better performance when you try to `JOIN` and find out the details pf products available in which cities.

At any point in time if you want to get back a comma separated list like `1,2,4` of values then you can do a `GROUP BY productid` and use `GROUP_CONCAT(cityid)` to get the same.

Comment: Also is even more easy to query multiple cities using **IN( multipleids )**,
Thanks :)